# sed: simultanous in-place replacement, and printout of changed lines?

Tags: shell, sed

Say I have this file:

```
cat > test.txt <<EOF
line one word
line two word
line three word
line one two word
EOF
```

And let's say I want to replace all of the words 'two' with 'TWO', <s>inline</s> *in-place* in the file `test.txt`.

Now, what I do, is usually construct a "preview" (with `-n` don't print lines, and then with `/p` - print matched lines only):

```
$ sed -n 's/two/TWO/gp' test.txt 
line TWO word
line one TWO word
```

... and then I usually execute the actual in-place replacement (with `-i`, and without `/p`):

```
$ sed -i 's/two/TWO/g' test.txt
$ cat test.txt 
line one word
line TWO word
line three word
line one TWO word
```

Is there a way to get `sed` to both change lines in-place in a file, *and* print the changed lines to stdout, from a single command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Linux, you may be able to get away with:

```
sed -i '/two/{s/two/TWO/g; w /dev/stdout}' test.txt
```

On BSD systems (including Mac OS X), where the `sed` has slightly eccentric rules about when you can combine actions onto a single line, I had to use:

```
sed -i '/two/{s/two/TWO/g; w /dev/stdout
       }' test.txt
```

Comment: Awesome - many thanks for that @Jonathan Leffler ! Btw, I'm on Ubuntu 11.04, and the first command line gave me "`sed: couldn't open file /dev/stdout}: Permission denied`"; when I put in a break after `stdout` like you did for the Mac, all worked great! Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Cheers to both of you--this also just helped me!

Comment: FWIW, you said that on Mac OS X "sed has slightly eccentric rules", actually it's just that OS X uses BSD sed, not GNU sed, which work a bit differently.