# Could we do dynamic replace in bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here we have 2 vars in bash shell

```
ID="ABC"

ID_STRING="Here is the [${ID}]"
```

Is there any approach that we could dynamic replace the var ${ID} to "ABC" in the ID_STRING and echo to concole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly the ID_STRING variable contains the literal string ${ID} when it is echoed to the screen and isn't assigned the way you show in the question - assigning it the way you have it in your question using double quotes means the ID_STRING variable never actually contains the literal string ${ID} because with double quotes the variable replacement is done as it is assigned.  So first: to get the literal string ${ID} into ID_STRING you need to use single quotes.  And second: you need to reevaluate ID_STRING as it is echoed.  I do it like this (the $ is the bash prompt):

```
$ ID=ABC
$ echo $ID
ABC

$ ID_STRING='Here is the [${ID}]'
$ echo $ID_STRING
Here is the [${ID}]

$ eval echo $ID_STRING
Here is the [ABC]

$ echo $ID, $ID_STRING, `eval echo $ID_STRING`
ABC, Here is the [${ID}], Here is the [ABC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You you want to replace `${ID}` from string:

```
ID="ABC"
sed 's/\${ID}/'$ID'/' filename
```

Output:

```
ID_STRING="Here is the "[ABC]"
```

---

If you want to use that value of `ID` while assigning the string to `ID_STRING`, you can use:

```
ID="ABC"
ID_STRING="Here is the [$ID]"
```

Now:

```
echo $ID_STRING
```

gives

```
Here is the [ABC]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -i -e 's/old/new/g' file
```

Is basically what you need, to output the  changes have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8236897).